# Stop IWizard for Warning Message

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, messagedialog

I am doing Eclipse plug-in development... When the user clicks finish, I am making a service call that will return three options.

```
1. Everything is okay to proceed
2. Give user warning
3. Stop Finish completely
```

So 1 and 3 are easy.

Here is what I am doing for 3:

```
IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, Activator.PLUGIN_ID, IStatus.OK, message, e);
throw new CoreException(status);
```

So this will just throw an exception and popup a message dialog with the message that I am passing to it.

I am stuck on number 2...

I have tried the following:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(null, theTitle, Dialog.getImage(Dialog.DLG_IMG_WARNING), dialogMessage, MessageDialog.WARNING, new String[]{"Yes", "No"}, 0);

int returnCode = dialog.open();
if(returnCode == 0){
    //proceed with finish
}
else if(returnCode == 1){
    //stop the finsih
    return;
}
```

Here is the message I am receiving when doing this:

```
null argument:The dialog should be created in UI thread
```

Is it possible to give the user a warning message after he clicks finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All UI code must be created and run in the UI thread. So if you want to display a dialog from some other thread and wait for the result use `Display.syncExec`:

```
final int [] returnCode = new int[1];

Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable()
     {
        @Override
        public void run()
        { 
           MessageDialog dialog = ....

           returnCode[0] = dialog.open();
        }
     });

if (returnCode[0] == 0)
.....
```